# Proxmox/Ubuntu LVM issue - Exec format error

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, proxmox

I've ran apt update / upgrade on my proxmox server and now I can't seem to boot it into the new kernel (didn't pay too much attention on the update).
Any ideas? I can't seem to figure out what's the issue with the LVM executable.
Any help would be really appreciated.

```
-bash: /usr/sbin/lvm: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
root@proxmox:~#
root@proxmox:~# lsblk
NAME                         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                            8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
└─sda1                         8:1    0 931.5G  0 part
sdb                            8:16   0 238.5G  0 disk
├─sdb1                         8:17   0  1007K  0 part
├─sdb2                         8:18   0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sdb3                         8:19   0   238G  0 part
  ├─pve-swap                 253:0    0     7G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─pve-root                 253:1    0  59.3G  0 lvm  /
  ├─pve-data_tmeta           253:2    0   1.6G  0 lvm
  │ └─pve-data-tpool         253:4    0 152.6G  0 lvm
  │   ├─pve-data             253:5    0 152.6G  0 lvm
  │   ├─pve-vm--100--disk--1 253:6    0     4M  0 lvm
  │   ├─pve-vm--100--disk--2 253:7    0    34G  0 lvm
  │   ├─pve-vm--102--disk--0 253:8    0    32G  0 lvm
  │   ├─pve-vm--103--disk--0 253:9    0    32G  0 lvm
  │   └─pve-vm--104--disk--0 253:10   0    32G  0 lvm
  └─pve-data_tdata           253:3    0 152.6G  0 lvm
    └─pve-data-tpool         253:4    0 152.6G  0 lvm
      ├─pve-data             253:5    0 152.6G  0 lvm
      ├─pve-vm--100--disk--1 253:6    0     4M  0 lvm
      ├─pve-vm--100--disk--2 253:7    0    34G  0 lvm
      ├─pve-vm--102--disk--0 253:8    0    32G  0 lvm
      ├─pve-vm--103--disk--0 253:9    0    32G  0 lvm
      └─pve-vm--104--disk--0 253:10   0    32G  0 lvm
sdc                            8:32   0 931.5G  0 disk
└─sdc1                         8:33   0 931.5G  0 part
root@proxmox:~# pvdisplay
-bash: /usr/sbin/pvdisplay: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
root@proxmox:~# file /usr/sbin/pvdisplay
/usr/sbin/pvdisplay: symbolic link to lvm
root@proxmox:~# which lvm
/usr/sbin/lvm
root@proxmox:~# file /usr/sbin/lvm
/usr/sbin/lvm: data
root@proxmox:~#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like something happened to upgrading the packages.  I would suspect something else is going on but you can try reinstalling LVM2:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall lvm2
```

then see if that helps anything.

Comment: hummm, simple as that, eh? It did help.. thank you so much... I'll try to reboot and see if system becomes stable. Thank you again, I'll revert either way.

Comment: Yes! it did fix my issue. Thank you so much.